# My private router "Technicolor TC7200k" was hacked. Need urgent advice, sensitive information was stolen

Tags: router, system-compromise

My colleague (and or my company) has hacked my home router and gained access to all my internet whereabouts. The router is a "Technicolor 7200k". How I found out about this does not matter at this point, but he uses it for personal gains.

I need advice on how to:

1. Catch them in the act. Have reliable proof so it would be viable in a court.
2. How to access the internet at home without him/them knowing. (i can have my router set to bridge mode so it functions as a modem instead of a router and use a custom router in the back, but i don't know if this will block them out.)

I am also willing to hire a security specialist in order have this sorted out,
but i don't know where to go. If there is a better platform that stackexchange,
please do tell me. I do live in Germany.

Comment: Even if you found proof that they were connecting through your router through your router's logs, the proof may be useless if they are using a proxy/VPN.  Also, if they were on their home IP, law enforcement still might not do anything.  Just get a new router, update it, and secure it.

Comment: Change the password on the router? This question is too undefined and too broad for us to answer. How you found out DOES matter because it is very possible that you are incorrect about the assumptions you have made about the problem (you might not be hacked at all).